# How do I load a class from another bundle using a URI or similar?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, classloader

Is it possible to load a class which is located in an other bundle using some kind of URI?

I noticed that in e4 classes can be identified using a URIs like this:

```
bundleclass://bundle_symbolic_name/full_classpath
```

Can I use this in 3.x applications?

Answer (score 2):

The code to handle the `bundleclass` URI seems to be hidden away in an internal class, but the basic method to do this is:

```java
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(bundle_symbolic_name);

Class<?> theClass = bundle.loadClass(full_classpath);
```

Comment: what's your experience with 'pure e4'? I had a quick look at it last weekend and it seems to be quite a lot of new stuff to learn. It is worth the hassle?

Comment: There is a lot of traditional Eclipse stuff that you can't use in e4 but for a new RCP the application model, dependency injection and css styling are nice. Eclipse 4.4 (Luna) allows some of this is a 3.x style app also,